# Node.js - Uploads only work with /var/www/example.com/html/ path. Nothing else

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I am using Node.js and Socket.io for chat application, also I implemented file uploader.

```
var uploader = new siofu();
uploader.dir = "images/uploads/";
uploader.mode = "0775";
uploader.listen(socket);
uploader.maxFileSize = 3000000;
```

Structure of folder is as follows:

```
www
-example.com
--html
--server.js //Actual Node.js server that's started.
---public
----images
-----uploads
```

I've tried following paths:

```
public/images/uploads/
public/images/uploads
/public/images/uploads/
/public/images/uploads
./public/images/uploads/
./public/images/uploads
```

And yet it doesn't work, server keeps throwing me ENOENT and file doesn't even upload.

However, when I set upload path to: /var/www/example.com/html/public/images/uploads 
it works just fine and uploads images perfectly.

Note: It worked before, but I had to do hard-reset of server and after that - this happened.

What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Most likely a permissions issue.  Ensure the owner and permissions are the same on the folder you want to upload to as they are on /var/www/example.com/html/public/images/uploads

Comment: @ShawnJacobson well all permissions on public/images/uploads are 755

Comment: Which means only the owner has write permissions.  Have you checked the owner of the directories?

Comment: @ShawnJacobson I've just tried 777 just for test purposes, still not finding it.

Comment: ./public/images/uploads/ should work...weird

Comment: @ShawnJacobson I've added screenshot to show what it gives me every time.

Comment: I would definitely use ./public/... instead of just public/... - not sure that would ever work (it might, but I've never done it that way).  I'll load up a test and see if I can reproduce.

Comment: @ShawnJacobson for some reason none of those work, and I tried ./public/ too. For time being my temporary fix is uploader.dir = __dirname+"/public/images/uploads";  which feels kinda cheap solution

Comment: I'm using Windows, but the using the example app at https://github.com/vote539/socketio-file-upload#example, both ./public/images/uploads/ and ./public/images/uploads works without issue.  If I have time tomorrow, I'll try on a linux box at work...sorry.

Comment: @ShawnJacobson okay thank you. I have feeling it's some node.js config line which I am unaware of, I am still new to node.